# Copying sublist structure to another list of equal length in Python

Tags: python, list

Say I have one list,

```
list1 = ['Dog', 'Cat', 'Monkey', 'Parakeet', 'Zebra']
```

And another,

```
list2 = [[True, True], [False], [True], [False]]
```

(You can imagine that the second list was created with an itertools.groupby on an animal being a house pet.)

Now say I want to give the first list the same sublist structure as the second.

```
list3 = [['Dog', 'Cat'], ['Monkey'], ['Parakeet'], ['Zebra']]
```

I might do something like this:

```
list3 = []
lengths = [len(x) for x in list2]
count = 0
for leng in lengths:
    templist = []
    for i in range(leng):   
        templist.append(list1[count])
        count += 1
    list3.append(templist)
```

Which I haven't totally debugged but I think should work. My question is if there is a more pythonic or simple way to do this? This seems kind of convoluted and I have to imagine there is a more graceful way to do it (maybe in itertools which never ceases to impress me).

Comment: @MEE no... it's not asking for review... and CR won't appreciate questions which are in a state of *Which I haven't totally debugged but I think should work*... please avoid recommending CR unless you're totally sure it's suitable.

Comment: I'm nearly positive the code works and the problem is fairly general. I frequently see many positive questions asking for a more 'pythonic' way of doing something so I didn't think this would be inappropriate here at all.

Comment: Shouldn't this be possible when using itertools, in the previous step?

Comment: Yeah I just don't know the specific way to do it with itertools (or whatever package does it). I just wanted to see if there is a more elegant way of doing it.

Comment: If the second list was created based on whether animal is house pet or not, shouldn't there be only 2 groups? No?

Comment: Thats not the way itertools.groupby works. It only does "consecutive" grouping". Generally you would be correct but that's not how this package works

Comment: You can always sort the list before passing it to `groupby`.

Comment: I actually want the 'consecutive grouping' functionality but that's not the point of this question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're okay with modifying the original list (if not, you can always copy first), you can use `pop()` in a list comprehension:

```
list1 = ['Dog', 'Cat', 'Monkey', 'Parakeet', 'Zebra']
list2 = [[True, True], [False], [True], [False]]

list3 = [[list1.pop(0) for j in range(len(x))] for x in list2]
print(list3)
#[['Dog', 'Cat'], ['Monkey'], ['Parakeet'], ['Zebra']]
```

Comment: Ah yes. This is a nice one-liner and I would say it is the most simple and 'pythonic'.  I think I like this one best (no offense to all the other great answers though!)

Comment: @sfortney just be wary that popping isn't particularly fast at the front of a list and that `list1` will be mutated - so make sure you don't need it after or anything else referencing it does because it'll be empty.

Comment: For this size of data - probably meh... as you'd then have to make a copy of list1 to pop from instead... and you'd lose the elegance the OP likes in this one...

Comment: Jon I was not aware of that. My use case doesn't have a ton of iterations to do though so readability beats performance in this application. That is a good point though!

Comment: Yea to avoid popping from the front, you'd have to do something like `list3 = [e for e in reversed([[list1.pop() for j in range(len(x))] for x in reversed(list2)])]`

Answer (score 11):

You can simply use `next` for a no-import solution:

```
list1 = ['Dog', 'Cat', 'Monkey', 'Parakeet', 'Zebra']
list_1 = iter(list1)
list2 = [[True, True], [False], [True], [False]]
new_list2 = [[next(list_1) for _ in i] for i in list2]
```

Output:

```
[['Dog', 'Cat'], ['Monkey'], ['Parakeet'], ['Zebra']]
```

However, for input `n` levels deep, you can use recursion:

```
list1 = ['Dog', 'Cat', 'Monkey', 'Parakeet', 'Zebra']
list_1 = iter(list1)
list2 = [[True, [True, False]], [False], [[True]]]
def place_data(current):
   return [next(list_1) if isinstance(i, int) else place_data(i) for i in current]

print(place_data(list2))
```

Output:

```
[['Dog', ['Cat', 'Monkey']], ['Parakeet'], [['Zebra']]]
```

Comment: I was just about to submit an edit to my answer with this... I won't now... :)

Comment: Nicely done with the recursion! Couldn't get my solution to work right.

Comment: I don't get why you use `isinstance(i, int)`... surely for this particular case `isinstance(i, bool)` is more appropriate. Even though I'd probably use `not isinstance(i, (list,tuple))` which works for more cases.

Comment: @Bakuriu: For maximal compatibility, you would want something like `not isinstance(i, collections.abc.Sequence)`, or even `Iterable` if you're dealing with some kind of lazy generator structure.

Comment: @Bakuriu `bool` is a subclass of `int`, and thus `isinstance(variable, int)` will work even if we are checking that `variable` is a boolean value.

Comment: @Ajax1234 I know that, and I have never said that it does not work. But what's the point of using `int` instead of `bool`? I don't see any good reason to do that. It simply allows using lists containing `int`s instead of just `bool`s, but if you instead used my proposal it would work for *any* element type. So I don't really see the point of doing it except for confusing other developers.

Answer (score 4):

Make an `iter` of `list1` and `islice` the necessary N elements of each list2,e g:

```
from itertools import islice

list1 = ['Dog', 'Cat', 'Monkey', 'Parakeet', 'Zebra']
list2 = [[True, True], [False], [True], [False]]

it = iter(list1)
list3 = [list(islice(it, len(el))) for el in list2]
# [['Dog', 'Cat'], ['Monkey'], ['Parakeet'], ['Zebra']]
```

Comment: This is very close, but if `list2` is nested deeper, it doesn't work: `[[True, True, [False]], [True], [False]]` -> `[['Dog', 'Cat', 'Monkey'], ['Parakeet'], ['Zebra']]`, not `[['Dog', 'Cat', ['Monkey']], ['Parakeet'], ['Zebra']]`

Comment: @Noah true... but that'd be a completely different question with different requirements in those cases... It also won't handle mixed data types or non-iterable/sequenced elements as sublists either... but again - that's not part of the question.

Answer (score 3):

This is one way:

```
from itertools import accumulate

idx_acc = [0] + list(accumulate(map(len, list2)))
list1 = [list1[i:j] for i, j in zip(idx_acc, idx_acc[1:])]

# [['Dog', 'Cat'], ['Monkey'], ['Parakeet'], ['Zebra']]
```

Comment: Thanks jp! This is probably the shortest solution one could make. It's not intuitively obvious to me what the point of the [0]+ at the beginning is though. Can you explain that?'

Comment: sure, the accumulator just gives the length of each list (>= 1). but in the list comprehension you need to specify start and end points. in this case, we need to start at 0 for the first element of the list comprehension.

Answer (score 3):

`itertools.groupby` allows you to do this already, because it returns the groups as well as the keys

```
def is_pet(animal):
    return animal.lower() in ('dog', 'cat', 'parakeet')

animals = ['Dog', 'Cat', 'Monkey', 'Parakeet', 'Zebra']
print([list(g) for k, g in itertools.groupby(animals, key=is_pet)])
# [['Dog', 'Cat'], ['Monkey'], ['Parakeet'], ['Zebra']]
```

The other option that springs to mind is to use an iterator over the list, something like

```
def group(to_group, group_like):
    it = iter(to_group)
    for sub_list in group_like:
        yield [next(it) for _ in sub_list]

print(list(group(list1, list2)))
# [['Dog', 'Cat'], ['Monkey'], ['Parakeet'], ['Zebra']]
```

Answer (score 2):

This replaces sublists with the list containing those elements, based on the length of the corresponding list in `list2`.

```
list3 = list1.copy()

j = 0
for i in range(len(list2)):
    list3[j:j+len(list2[i])] = [list3[j:j+len(list2[i])]]
    j += 1
```

Comment: I like this one. It's fairly comprehensible and neat.

Answer (score 1):

There's a nice recursive way that works for arbitrary nesting:

```
def to_structure(lst, stru):
  lst = iter(lst)
  for elem in stru:
    if isinstance(elem, list):
      yield list(to_structure(lst, elem))
    else:
      yield next(lst, None) # replace missing elements with None
      # alternately, raise ValueError (see also pep 479)
      # try:
      #   yield next(lst)
      # except StopIteration:
      #   raise ValueError("Not enough elements")

list(to_structure(range(4), [[0,0],[0],[[0]]])) # -> [[0, 1], [2], [[3]]]
list(to_structure(range(3), [[0,0],[0],[[0]]])) # -> [[0, 1], [2], [[None]]]
```